# Unable to set only one checkbox selected in a listview

Tags: android, listview, checkbox

I have a listview that each item in listview contains a checkbox. My problem is i want to set only one checkbox selected at a time. Another problem is when i select a checkbox in order 3, then when i scroll up and back, checkbox is checked in different order 5 or 8 randomly
Could you help me solve this issue

Comment: Thisis because of the way in which listview recycling mechanism works. You need to post relevant adapter code

Comment: Probably what you want is a radio button rather than checkbox. Also, to get better response, post the relevant code.

Comment: take a boolean in listview object for check and uncheck and change its value if checked true and false if uncheck and in place of taking android checkbox, use a checkbox image let's say checked.png and unchecked.png use it according to check status.

Comment: I know, every item when i scroll up and back, listview is redrawn. Do you know where i can get clear concept about it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Set your listview to :

```
lvSelectLocation.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
ArrayAdapter<String> adptr = new ArrayAdapter<String>(Location.this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, locationList);
```

Handle onItemClick only :

```
lvSelectLocation.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int arg2,
                    long arg3) {
                    Selected = arg0.getItemAtPosition(arg2).toString();
            }
        });
```

Android automatically recycle the listview view so, selected option is recycle when you scroll. For that you have to set the selected list item to your ArrayList.

Comment: You welcome. If the answer is helpful then select as a correct answer.

Comment: How can i handle it in case of RecyclerView

Comment: check this links : http://joshskeen.com/building-a-radiogroup-recyclerview/ and  https://bignerdranch.github.io/recyclerview-multiselect/

Answer (score 0):

You can use the API demo to understand the best way for this implementation.
Have a look on [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/development/+/master/samples/ApiDemos/src/com/example/android/apis/view/List10.java).
There is a `CHOCIE_MODE` option with the list view you can set it to `CHOCIE_MODE_SINGLE`. Simple code is like this-

```
public class List10 extends ListActivity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_single_choice, GENRES));

        final ListView listView = getListView();
        listView.setItemsCanFocus(false);
        listView.setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
    }
    private static final String[] GENRES = new String[] {
        "Action", "Adventure", "Animation", "Children", "Comedy", "Documentary", "Drama",
        "Foreign", "History", "Independent", "Romance", "Sci-Fi", "Television", "Thriller"
    };
}
```